# Invalid Image Asset

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect, tvos, apple-tv

When trying to upload a tvOS archive to iTunesConnect, I get the following error:

> Invalid Image Asset. The image asset 'App Icon - Small' in 'Payload/[APPNAME].app' has an invalid scale value of '3'. Home Screen Icon assets are allowed scale values of ( "1" )."

I assume this problem will occur for the 'App Icon - Large' as well once I fix the small icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layers of my stacked image icon were vector PDFs. Converting these layers to static PNG format at a 1x scale solved the problem.